# How to resolve "NuGet package restore failed" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I got an error

> NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.

while building my solution. Package manager can't restore my 2 projects:

> Unable to find project information for 'C:\(...)\MultiLinker.Courier.Dext.Model.csproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.

In tools I allow package manage to download packages:

[image]

Comment: In the Solution Explorer - Do you see a project by name "MultiLinker.Courier.Dext.Model.csproj" - Is it in Unloaded state? Seems like that project is broken.

Answer (score 35):

Ran into the same issue. In my case, it was because Visual Studio only had the Offline Package source and could not resolve the packages I needed. I added in the nuget.org source as shown below in the NuGet Package Manager settings and right clicked on the solution and selected restore packages. and it resolved the issue.

[image: screen cap]

Comment: I just spent a couple hours on this. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: The nuget api url is now updated to v3
https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/

Answer (score 11):

open Nuget Package Manager -> Package Source > Add  https://nuget.org/api/v2

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was my Company DevOps credentials being out of date

Account Settings > Change credentials in the dialog that opens

Answer (score 2):

I might be forgetting some steps, but a crucial step for me to fix this was running `nuget restore` from the commandline (Trying to restore from Visual Studio UI was not sufficient for some reason).

I also added a plugins folder given to me by a teammate to my .nuget folder that supposedly makes it handle our credentials automatically, so if you are having this issue maybe that is something you are missing as well.

Answer (score 2):

On Visual Studio Code (VSCode) this can be solved this way:

```
dotnet new nugetconfig
```

Comment: I kept getting some cached nuget sources trying to restore and this was the only thing that prevented them from doing so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my out of date Visual Studio helped for me:

Help Menu: Check for Updates...

Comment: I had the same symptoms as the original question and updating visual studio fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

thank you it works fine
and solved all issues of nuget
by creating the new value in the setting of nuget
under tools > nuget package manger > package manger settings
nuget package sources
add new value nuget.org and https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

then save and update you project
it will work

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, I use Visual Studio 2013.

This worked for me:

1. Click on Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console
2. Paste the following lines on the console: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Then, rebuild your solution.

Answer (score -1):

The nuget restore did not work for me but once I used nuget.org it worked just fine. This was the best solution for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).